# react-native props autocomplete for webstorm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am using react-native type definitions (@types/react-native), all working well unless props autocomplete is it possible to solve this problem? [image: no suggestion area]

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: use https://code.visualstudio.com/ and install the react native extenstion